# Why all checkbox of column getting checked when checking single checkbox - Angular table

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on table. one column of table has checkboxes. When I am clicking one checkbox all checkbox of that column getting checked.

This is my code

```
<td>                   
<label class="container"> 
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox"  data-md-icheck (change)="toggleVisibility($event)"/>
      Checkbox is <span *ngIf="marked">checked</span><span *ngIf="!marked">unchecked</span>
  </label>
</td>
```

toggleVisibility function is empty

```
toggleVisibility(data)
{
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: if you has an unique variable, "theCheckBox", all has the same value. define an array theCheckBox:boolean[]=[], and use theCheckBox[i], or if you iterating over an array of object use some like element.theCheckBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<table >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}} </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr  *ngFor="let el of elements;let index = index;">
      <th scope="row">{{el.id}}</th>
      <td>{{el.first}}</td>
      <td>{{el.last}}</td>
      <td>                   

    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="el.checked" >
    <span *ngIf="el.checked" >checked</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnrmpp?file=src/app/app.component.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can I get selected record, as per my code in .ts file. Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmd8r9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide different  "for" attribute of lable and different "id" for each input

```
 <td>                   
 <label class="container" for="theCheckbox"> 
   <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox"  id="theCheckbox" data-md-icheck (change)="toggleVisibility($event)"/>
  Checkbox is <span *ngIf="marked">checked</span><span *ngIf="!marked">unchecked</span>
   </label>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using same variable for all columns in *ngIf and for [(ngModel)]:

```
<span *ngIf="marked">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox">
```

this variable 'marked' and 'theCheckbox' is repeated for all the columns. So, in one column if it is changed it will reflect in others too. You provided only your  code. Provide your table code too. So that it will be more clear.

You can resolve this by providing unique key for each check box in each column.